# Insert specific N blank rows depending on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame looking like this :

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1,0,2,0,1,3,1),
+                  y = c("lima","chicago","new york","Miami","havana","Colon","la paz"))
> df
  x        y
1 1     lima
2 0  chicago
3 2 new york
4 0    Miami
5 1   havana
6 3    Colon
7 1   la paz
```

I would like to find a way to insert blank N rows depending on the value of column `x`
so if `x` is 1, 1 blank row would be inserted above, if `x` is 3, 3 blank rows would be inserted above. The desired output for the data frame above should be this:

```
> df
    x        y
1  NA     <NA>
2   1     lima
3   0  chicago
4  NA     <NA>
5  NA     <NA>
6   2 new york
7   0    Miami
8  NA     <NA>
9   1   havana
10 NA     <NA>
11 NA     <NA>
12 NA     <NA>
13  3    Colon
14 NA     <NA>
15  1   la paz
```

Comment: Feels a bit like an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem? I'm sure something like this can be done, but I have a feeling this is an intermediate step to what you are actually trying to achieve? If not I apologize, if so, it might be a good idea to explain why you would want to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions seems that way, so let me try to clarify, you can think of column x as the number of days it took to get to that city from the previous city in column y, so if you look at the initial df, from Chicago to New York, there is 2 days of travel, therefore i need to insert to blank rows in between Chicago and network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do it this way:
We group by row number and add to each row number x + 1 rows.
Using a trick we can show the NA's first:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  summarise(cur_data()[seq(x+1),]) %>% 
  arrange(!is.na(x), x, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-ID)
```

```
       x y       
   <dbl> <chr>   
 1    NA NA      
 2     1 lima    
 3     0 chicago 
 4    NA NA      
 5    NA NA      
 6     2 new york
 7     0 Miami   
 8    NA NA      
 9     1 havana  
10    NA NA      
11    NA NA      
12    NA NA      
13     3 Colon   
14    NA NA      
15     1 la paz
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R base

```
do.call(rbind, c(make.row.names=FALSE, lapply(split(df, df$y), function(z){
  x <- y <- rep(NA, z$x)
  rbind(cbind(x, y), z)
}) ))
    x        y
1   0  chicago
2  NA     <NA>
3  NA     <NA>
4  NA     <NA>
5   3    Colon
6  NA     <NA>
7   1   havana
8  NA     <NA>
9   1   la paz
10 NA     <NA>
11  1     lima
12  0    Miami
13 NA     <NA>
14 NA     <NA>
15  2 new york
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option

```
i1 <-with(df, rep(seq_along(x), ifelse(x >0, x + 1, 1)))
out <- df[NA^(duplicated(i1, fromLast = TRUE)) * i1,]
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
    x        y
1  NA     <NA>
2   1     lima
3   0  chicago
4  NA     <NA>
5  NA     <NA>
6   2 new york
7   0    Miami
8  NA     <NA>
9   1   havana
10 NA     <NA>
11 NA     <NA>
12 NA     <NA>
13  3    Colon
14 NA     <NA>
15  1   la paz
```